# Find objects by their children using TypeORM for PostgreSQL

Tags: javascript, postgresql, typeorm

I have one parent entity called A, which has a relation with it's child B.

```
@Entity()
class A {
  status: boolean

  @OneToOne(() => B, (b) => b.a, {
    eager: true,
    nullable: true,
    cascade: true,
    onDelete: "CASCADE",
  })
  @JoinColumn()
  public b?: B;
}
```

I want to run a query with constraints on both, something like:

`dataSource.getRepository(A).find({where: { createdAt: '2022',}})`

and at the same time, I only want to get objects A which has B with some id. Something like

`dataSource.getRepository(A).find({where: { createdAt: '2022', this.B.id: '1234'}})`

Is this possible with TypeORM ?

Comment: Take a look here. This has examples https://orkhan.gitbook.io/typeorm/docs/find-options